# Problems with `\itemize` and the svmono document class

Tags: itemize, sv-classes

I have a strange behavior of the indentation in `\itemize` environment if I use the Springer's `svmono` document class. Look the following example:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[(E1)]She can access to an arbitrarily large number of ciphertexts, in other words she intercepts all the communications between Alice and Bob.
\item[(E2)]She always knows the encrypting and decrypting functions.
\end{itemize}
```

The result is:
[image]

Why I have this problem?

**Edit:** I use the following packages

```
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[colorlinks={true},linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
```

Comment: Why do you have this problem? Mainly because the `svmono` class in badly written, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have this problem. Do you use any other commands that could affect the itemizing?

Maybe you can try this:

```
 \documentclass{svmono}

 \usepackage{enumitem}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}[label=(E\arabic*),start=1]
 \item She can access to an arbitrarily large number of ciphertexts, in other words she intercepts all the communications between Alice and Bob.
 \item She always knows the encrypting and decrypting functions.
 \end{enumerate}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I've edited my question with the packages in use.

Comment: I tried to compile with your packages (pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex) and both examples work as they should do.

Comment: Maybe I have an older version of svmono, where can I download the newest version?

Comment: [Monographs - Using LaTeX2e](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0)

Comment: `\itemize` doesn't work! It's a mystery. However many thanks for the help.

Comment: Btw `enumerate` works!